# Crystal report textobject and fields

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am running the following code

```
foreach (ReportObject obj in oSectionObjects)
{
    if (obj.Kind == CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.TextObject)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

but i have a problem. i do have multiple text that do contain text AND fields in them.
But crystal return me the field being `TextObject` which is technically true.

How do i know i ONLY have text in the `TextObject` and not anything else (aka fields, parameters, formulas) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched alot around and found working solution for RAS report but nothing for crystal. Anyhow if someone end up here looking for an answer here's the work around.

Whenever you have to concatenate multiple fields on the report do NOT use `TextObject`. Instead use a `Formula`. The formula fields wont bet part of the `ReportObjects` but instead part of the `ReportDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields` with `Kind` being `CrystalDecisions.Shared.FieldKind.FormulaField` and you will want to check the `ValueType` so it is `CrystalDecisions.Shared.FieldValueType.StringField`.

then you can manipulate them.

I did need that for translation of report live so here's a parsing method for formulas :

```
try
{
    var sFormula = formula.Text;
    string pattern = "\"[\\w ]*\"";
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
    MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(sFormula);

    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        var sValue =m.Value;
        var sParsedValue = sValue.Substring(1, sValue.Length - 2);

        if (sParsedValue.StartsWith("s"))
        {
            var stest = "\"" + CApplicationData.TranslateStringValue(sParsedValue) + "\"";
            sFormula = sFormula.Replace(sValue, stest);
        }
    }

    formula.Text = sFormula;
}
catch{}
```

this above you will notice i use 's' as a key to know it might be a value to be translated so it's not mandatory. using the above on this formula with Spanish language :

`"sPage" + " " + totext(PageNumber) + " " + "sOf" + " " + totext(TotalPageCount)`

will modify the formula to :

`"Página" + " " + totext(PageNumber) + " " + "de" + " " + totext(TotalPageCount)`

giving output of :

`Página 1 de 4`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the fields in a text box will be recognized by the text pattern. Try to search the text of the text object for {1@xxxxx} where xxxxx is the field name. "{1@" shows the type of the field: 1 is for a database , 2 is for formula, 3 is for parameter. You may try also for {@xxxxx} *(without numeric field identifier)

Comment: Had tried that but got issue when actual real data show like that. Anyhow i was requested to modify value evenwithin those textobject but as soon as you change text the fields are not linked anymore and when you generate the report any text object with text inside like : `"the value is : {data.quantity}"` with show the `{data.quantity}` as text if you modify